# Does the Adblock Plus extension prevent malicious code from downloading/executing?

Tags: security, adblock, malware

Firefox and Chrome are my favourite browsers. The main reason is an extension called Adblock Plus. Basically, it blocks all the ad networks if you subscribe to one of the lists, like EasyList. Does it also protect against malicious ads on completely legitimate websites? For instance, several news websites use ad services that may allow a malicious user to insert "evil code". This makes the web very unsafe, especially for those who lack a serious antivirus product.

Comment: This is more suitable for [Super User](http://superuser.com). But, no, Adblock Plus shouldn't be treated as protection from malicious code. It could block some malicious code from being executed, but that's incidental. It's better to keep your browser and browser plugins up to date and avoid sketchy sites than to rely on an adblocker to keep you safe.